# Where is Windows.Phone.UI.Input located?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to get my feet wet with Windows Phone 8.1. I was trying to handle HardwareButtons.BackPressed by hooking it to a customized event handler in order to prevent the back button from suspending my app. I think HardwareButtons is defined in Windows.Phone.UI.Input but when I tried to include:

```
using Windows.Phone.UI.Input;
```

The compiler was throwing out error saying:

```
The type or namespace name 'Phone' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

From previous questions:
[PresentationFramework DLL could not be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991675/presentationframework-dll-could-not-be-loaded)

[The type or namespace name 'Window' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621465/the-type-or-namespace-name-window-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-wind)

It appears that the presentationframework.dll maybe residing in the assembly gac but I can not find it anywhere in my machine.

Could someone show me where is the dll so that I can add it to the references or does windows 8.1 works differently? This is my first attempt to write a program for windows phone 8.1. My system is Surface Pro 2 with windows 8.1 and I use vs2013 premium. If this is the behavior of surface pro by design, I would need guidance to how to customize the BackPressed handler so that when it is pressed, it will not kick me out of my app.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed` event is for Windows Phone Runtime App. I seems that you create a new Windows Phone Silverlight App. Silverlight app doesn't have this event.

For Silverlight app, `PhoneApplicationPage` has an event:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Occurs when the hardware Back button is pressed.
    public event EventHandler<CancelEventArgs> BackKeyPress;
```

Subscribe and handle this event for your situation please.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. However I am pretty sure I used winRT (I created a new project from the installed template>Visual C#>StoreApps>Universal Apps>Blank App and not from Silverlight. How do I verify if Silverlight was not used for sure? I am very new to VS2013 but I am not new to programming, I just want to double check.

Comment: @user1205746 if you create a universal app, you should be careful only files that place in project named "App*.WindowsPhone" can use this `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` API.

Comment: Yep... that's it! I need to put it in the code related to phone only not both.

Answer (score 3):

Though not sure if this goes in here, but, for Windows UWP (10) apps, you need to add Windows Mobile Extensions reference to the project.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle back button pressed event you can use the following code

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   //Do your work here
   base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```

I dont think you require any additional namespaces to do this.
And regarding "preventing suspension of your app during a back press" I am not sure if it complies with the store certification requirements.